# Firefox addon - can I listen for prompts handled by nsIPromptService?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Firefox exposes this service:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIPromptService

Great! It is possible to make firefox display all kind of prompts, alerts, confirm boxes etc.

But can I register event listener anywhere? Basically I want to know when any `alert`, `confirm`, `basic auth` prompt, or even `<select>` options list appears on the screen. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already found out, there is a `DOMWillOpenModalDialog` event. This event might be sufficient for your needs, but you should keep some things in mind:

- You need to actually add an event listener to all windows that you're interested in and that could open a modal dialog.
- The event will be fired not only for `nsIPromptService` windows, but also for tab-modal (pseudo windows) and all other modal dialogs, such as Filepicker windows, sub-windows of the main preferences window, custom add-on provided windows.

There are other possible solutions, though:

- [Override `nsIPromptService`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559849/how-to-overwrite-built-in-xpcom-component-in-firefox-addon) with your own implementation. You would then just keep a reference to the original implementation around that you got prior and pass the calls along after inspecting them or whatever.
- You can overlay the actual modal prompt windows like any other XUL window, at least on Firefox Desktop, e.g. `chrome://global/content/commonDialog.xul` and/or `chrome://global/content/selectDialog.xul` to customize the window even more.

Answer (score 0):

I found `DOMWillOpenModalDialog` event but I am not yet sure if it satisfies all criteria, especially `<select>` options:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMWillOpenModalDialog